# Can I use JS to add async to a script tag in an iframe in such a way that it will actually affect the script page loading?

Tags: javascript, iframe, dom-events

It seems that the Stripe JavaScript is adding nearly 1/2 a second of main-thread blocking to my site. According to the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including), it's totally fine to either `async` or `defer` their JS. In fact, they say that if you include it through `npm` it does this automatically. This is probably what I would have done if I were implementing this on my own, but I'm using Stripe through a WordPress plugin that, whatever they're doing, is pulling the Stripe JS in through an iFrame, and not setting `async`:

```
<iframe name="__privateStripeController5481" ...>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/shared-0950781806f615c0693abdcbbb4bfc19.js"></script>
            <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/js/controller-842819e3871bc12ac5b51fa16b375c03.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

I'm thinking there should be some way to fix this, without waiting on the plugin developers to do it on their own. My idea is to do something like:

```
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() {
    const ifrm = document.getElementById('ifrm'); 
    const scripts = ifrm.contentDocument? 
                    ifrm.contentDocument: ifrm.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (const element of scripts) {
        element.hasAttribute('async') ? {} : element.setAttribute('async', '');
    }
};
```

But `onload`, will, I'm pretty sure, be way too late. Is there a way to accomplish this modification such that it happens early enough that the scripts in the iFrame end up being non-blocking?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change how the `script` tag is processed *after* the browser has read it from the HTML and started processing it. (Not least because your page and the `iframe` are running on the same one main UI thread — the very thread being blocked by that `script` tag.)

You'll have to modify the plugin's code. (And perhaps do a PR to get it adopted by the plugin project maintainers.)